# AJAX/JQUERY strange behaviour for special chars

Tags: ajax, post, character-encoding, ckeditor

Hello I'm developing a simple application where the user can change a content in a database by simply clicking "edit and save" without page refreshes. This is done with Jquery, AJAX POST and CKeditor (the textarea from where the content is retrieved)

If I write in CKeditor textarea "Hello this is a test!" I get

```
<p>Hello this is  a text</p>
```

and everything works fine. If I write "Hello this is a cool test, isn't it?" I get:

```
<p> Hello this is a cool test, isn&#39;t it?</p>
```

as it should be. This is ALSO sent via POST/JQuery/AJAX (verified via FireBug) but strangely in the PHP script that receivices the string if I echo the value passed I get

```
<p> Hello this is a cool test, isn
```

How is that possible?
Thank you

**EDIT SOLUTION FOUND:**
I had to add `encodeURIComponent(content)` in the ajax sent data

Comment: the problem seems to be the "&", any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly are you putting the data together and POSTing it? You need to use `encodeURIComponent`, however normally JQuery should be doing that for you.